Installed tabulapdf and rJava in R but using example code causes abort?
I'm trying to scrape table data from pdfs in R and so I've installed and loaded tabulapdf and rJava packages. The packages themselves appear to be loaded fully (initially had problems with Java but resolved them), however every time I run some example code, I get the 'fatal error / R Session aborted' message. Does anyone have advice on how to troubleshoot? My example code was
f <- system.file("examples", "mtcars.pdf", package = "tabulapdf")
extract_tables(f, pages = 2)
Java version says "1.8.0_431"

From check my Java from R at bottom @rafa.pereira, what does rJava::.jinit() # start Java, rJava::.jcall('java.lang.System', 'S', 'getProperty', 'java.version'),  show as a preliminary step.
